# why is my async storage returning previously stored value?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, asyncstorage

So, I was working on authentication and I wanted to store values (object) in that storage. But I tried a sample first. The problem with the code is that it is returning previously stored value. I don't know if the problem is with the useState. But I did make sure that was not the issue.

```
function App() {
const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const storeData = async () => {
    const value={
    "name":"jameel",
    "email":"caseyvlogger2311",
    "age":"23",
  }
    try {
      const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value)
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@profile', jsonValue)
      console.log("saved")
      console.log('console after saving (original value): ' + value.name)
    } catch (e) {
      // saving error
    }
  }
  const getData = async () => {
    console.log('console in getData (user useState name): ' + user.name)
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@profile')
      jsonValue != null ? setUser(JSON.parse(jsonValue)) : null;
      console.log("console useState value after getting data: " + user.name)
    } catch(e) {
      // error reading value
    }
  }
  return (
    <Button onPress={storeData}>Save data</Button>
    <Button onPress={getData}>Get data</Button>
  )
}
```

Output when I save and then get the value immediately:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJJPl.png)

Please let me know if there is something missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `setUser` is asynchronous as well.

Thus when you do

```
jsonValue != null ? setUser(JSON.parse(jsonValue)) : null;
console.log("console useState value after getting data: " + user.name)
```

you are triggering a state change, but this hasn't been executed yet when you access `user.name`, thus `user` still has the same value as in the current state. If you do

```
console.log(jsonValue)
```

you probably will see the "correct" value read from the storage ...

And just as a sidenote: Misusing the ternary operator `? :` as sort of an `if` in a statement is considered bad style. It's harder to read and may lead to errors on refactoring. Why not just just do

```
if (jsonValue != null) {
  setUser(JSON.parse(jsonValue));
}
```

instead? Is much easier to read and the intentions of that code perfectly clear ...